# HTML5 Canvas - Drag and Drop co-ordinates on rescale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

```js
//VARIABLES
//Drag Object Size
dragRadius = 100;
//Destination Size
destHeight = 434;
destWidth = 220;


var RosieDrag = new lib.RosieDrag();


//Drag Object Creation
//Placed inside a container to hold both label and shape

var test = new lib.test();
stage.addChild(test);
test.x = 525;
test.y = 1035;
var dragger = new createjs.Container();
dragger.x = 250;
dragger.y = 460;
dragger.addChild(RosieDrag);
dragger.setBounds(100, 100, dragRadius*2, dragRadius*2);
//DragRadius * 2 because 2*r = width of the bounding box



var RosieDrop = new lib.RosieDrop();
var destination = new createjs.Container();
destination.x = 900;
destination.y = 240;
destination.setBounds(950, 350, 100, 100);

destination.addChild(RosieDrop);

//DRAG FUNCTIONALITY =====================
dragger.on("pressmove", function(evt){
     evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
    evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;
     stage.update(); //much smoother because it refreshes the screen every pixel movement instead of the FPS set on the Ticker
     if(intersect(evt.currentTarget, destination)){
       evt.currentTarget.alpha=0.2;
       
     }else{
       evt.currentTarget.alpha=1;
            }

});

//Mouse UP and SNAP====================
dragger.on("pressup", function(evt) {
  if(intersect(evt.currentTarget, destination)){
  test.gotoAndPlay(5); 
    dragger.x = destination.x + destWidth/2;
    dragger.y = destination.y + destHeight/2;
    dragger.alpha = 1;
     stage.update(evt);
   }
});
//Tests if two objects are intersecting
//Sees if obj1 passes through the first and last line of its
//bounding box in the x and y sectors
//Utilizes globalToLocal to get the x and y of obj1 in relation
//to obj2
//PRE: Must have bounds set for each object
//Post: Returns true or false
function intersect(obj1, obj2){
  var objBounds1 = obj1.getBounds().clone();
  var objBounds2 = obj2.getBounds().clone();

  var pt = obj1.globalToLocal(objBounds2.x, objBounds2.y);
  
  var h1 = -(objBounds1.height / 2 + objBounds2.height);
  var h2 = objBounds2.width / 2;
  var w1 = -(objBounds1.width / 2 + objBounds2.width);
  var w2 = objBounds2.width / 2;
 
  
  if(pt.x > w2 || pt.x < w1) return false;
  if(pt.y > h2 || pt.y < h1) return false;
  
  return true;
}


//Adds the object into stage
stage.addChild(destination, dragger);
stage.mouseMoveOutside = true;
stage.update();
```

Hi,

I've made a simple drag and drop in a canvas. It works fine but when the canvas resizes to the window it changes the position of the object when it is picked up and also of the drop area (Interestingly it still draws things in the right position and places the object in the right position after it is dropped.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, here's my code:

Comment: I can look in to it, but to debug I'd need the dependencies such as lib, stage and createjs. Are you able to share them?